# How to parse python module for openstack

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack, iso8601

Recently, when I was installing openstack on 3 vm on centos 7 using answer file I had the following error:

> 10.7.35.174_osclient.pp:                          [ ERROR ]
>   Applying Puppet manifests                         [ ERROR ]
>
> ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 10.7.35.174_osclient.pp
>
> Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list python-iso8601' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
>
> You will find full trace in log /var/tmp/packstack/20160318-124834-91QzZC/manifests/10.7.35.174_osclient.pp.log
>   Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20160318-124834-91QzZC/openstack-setup.log for more information
>   Additional information:
>    * Time synchronization installation was skipped. Please note that unsynchronized time on server instances might be problem for some OpenStack components.
>    * File /root/keystonerc_admin has been created on OpenStack client host 10.7.35.174. To use the command line tools you need to source the file.
>    * To access the OpenStack Dashboard browse to http://10.7.35.174/dashboard .
>   Please, find your login credentials stored in the keystonerc_admin in your home directory.

I have already manually installed that module, but the same problem occures anyway.
That command only runs like that:

```
/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list python2-iso8601
```

Is there any way to parse it to python?

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that kilo version works fine.